# How to get the missing field from a mongo record

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, models

I have the data in my record:

```
{
"test" : "388383",
"geo1" : "[-75.603554,35.888575]",
"zip" : "[27959]"
}

var det = new Schema({  test: String})
```

I have zip field in my record but when I console it its not coming up.

```
Data.find({}).exec(function(err,data){
      console.log(data[0].zip)  ------> 'undefined'
      console.log(data[0].geo1) ------> "[-75.603554,35.888575]"

});
```

I did not declared it in my model (both the fields) but I an get geo1 not zip.

Comment: How is the data being inserted in the DB?

Comment: What's the schema?

Comment: @Frax,its a c file i just imported it by $ mongoimport -d mydb -c things --type csv --file locations.csv --headerline

Comment: Not possible... If the fields are in collection then they will be coming... Doesn't matter whether they are defined in schema or not... You are making some mistake or using some projection

Comment: I am fetching them by poplulate method is that a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Have your schema defined completely.

instead of this

```
  var det = new Schema({  test: String})
```

try

```
  var det = new Schema({  test: String,geo1:[Number],zip:[Number]});
```

Because if you wont have your schema defining each and every field, you wont be able to fetch all the data from a collection of a DB.